# Why can't wake up this thread

Tags: java, multithreading, wakeup

I want to test Thread.sleep() method, and I found a interesting thing.. 
When I invoke main() method , the console will print "UserA sleeping..." and "UserA waking...", that means the program is awakened , but when I use a junit method to run the same code as main() method,  it won't print "UserA waking..." ...    I  will be appreciate anyone can explain it .

```
package com.lmh.threadlocal;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new Thread(new UserA()).start();
    }
    @Test
    public void testWakeup(){
        new Thread(new UserA()).start();
    }

}

class UserA implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("UserA sleeping...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("UserA waking...");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more debugging statements at the start and end of `testWakeup` . Like, at start - "Spawning a new thread".

Comment: but why invoking main() method needn't wake up ???

Comment: How are you running the JUnit test?  I suspect that it is something to do with the JUnit test *runner*; e.g. it could be calling `System.exit()` soon after the return from `testWakeup`.  Or it could be killing child threads ... though I think that is unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that JUnit is tearing down the test before the sleep finishes, because the test execution thread exits the test method before the sleep finishes. Try

```
@Test
public void testWakeup() throws Exception {
    Thread t = new Thread(new UserA());
    t.start();
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: If the Thread is not a daemon thread, It also should print, am I right?

Comment: This answer doesn't really explain how / why the "tear down" stops the second println from happening ...

Comment: @StephenC is right, although it would work , I am still a little confused why it stops second println .